# Yahoo with WP8 GDR2 CardDAV / CalDAV

Tags: email, contacts, calendars, accounts

WP8 GDR2 supports CardDAV and CalDAV when adding a Google account. It was very easy--pick Google when adding an account and the rest was magic; contacts and calendar now sync.

I have a Yahoo! account (whose servers support CardDAV and CalDAV [1]) that I'd very much like to sync the calendar and contacts as well. When I add the account in my phone as a Yahoo account type, however, it just syncs mail with IMAP and ignores the rest. I attempted also to add the Yahoo account as a Google account, thinking I'd be able to override the server addresses (I was wrong).

Is there any way to add a Yahoo account to a GDR2 WP8 device with mail, contacts and calendar?

[1] http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&id=SLN5729

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed possible. I added my own CalDAV and CardDAV servers this way:

1. Add a new Google account and enter some random account data. The login should fail.
2. Reboot your phone (this is important!)
3. Select the just added Google account and change the default IMAP, CalDAV and CardDAV settings to your own ones (those from Yahoo).
4. Save, activate and sync.

Now you should have your emails as well as your calendar and address book synced.

Comment: Very clever! I couldn't figure out how to get past the credentials failure dialog to edit the server settings--I'll try the reboot trick shortly (it's actually a friend's phone) and mark as answer if it works.

Comment: This hack definitely works around the restriction of only allowing Google servers. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the Yahoo Cal/CardDav endpoints, caldav.calendar.yahoo.com. The phone gives an error, "We're having a problem synchronizing your information ... Error code: 801901F5." Google gives *nothing* for that error code :(

Comment: @TravisPettijohn same thing happened trying to use POBox.com's Cal/Card Dav servers :(

Comment: This isn't working for me (WP8.1u1). If I don't put in real credentials, the account doesn't get created at all. If I do, I can't change the email address or user name of the created account.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try our app, Purple Contacts!

Purple Contacts lets you copy Yahoo Contacts to your Windows Phone:

http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=14c047f6-fb90-43b1-9847-32c56af05f47

We charge a small bit for it - which we think is reasonable versus the amount of time it would take you to manually enter your Yahoo Contacts.

Give it a try!